# Meaning of kpsewhich

Tags: tex-history

I know that `kpsewhich` comes from an extend version of `kpathsea` so this deals with `kpse` in `kpsewhich`.

But is the `k` comes from `KDE` or not ?

Comment: BTW, `kpathsea` is older than KDE ...

Comment: @JosephWright I wondered if that was the case. When did `kpathsea` appear?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. `texdoc kpathsea` has a day-by-day account of the early history:-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It does not, the `k` comes from Karl Berry. `kpathsea` stands for "Karl's path searching" according to http://tug.org/interviews/berry.html